# Change the position of element in List

Tags: java, list, scala, collections, scala-collections

There is a `List` in `scala`

```
var list=List("scala","finagle","anorm","akka","actor","play","jdbc")
```

If it is containing an element like `"akka"` then i want to move it to the 1st position.

```
List("akka","scala","finagle","anorm","actor","play","jdbc")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's only one "akka" at most:

```
var (before, after) = list.span(_ != "akka")
//> before  : List[String] = List(scala, finagle, anorm)
//| after  : List[String] = List(akka, actor, play, jdbc)

if (after.isEmpty) list else "akka" :: (before ::: after.tail)
//> res0: List[String] = List(akka, scala, finagle, anorm, actor, play, jdbc)
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this (note, I added an extra copy of "akka" near the end of the input string to show how it collects all matching strings):

```
scala> val inList = List("scala","finagle","anorm","akka","actor","play","akka","jdbc")
inList: List[String] = List(scala, finagle, anorm, akka, actor, play, akka, jdbc)

scala> val partitioned = inList.partition(_ == "akka") // Or whatever partition function suits your need
partitioned: (List[String], List[String]) = (List(akka, akka),List(scala, finagle, anorm, actor, play, jdbc))

scala> val outList = partitioned._1 ::: partitioned._2
outList: List[String] = List(akka, akka, scala, finagle, anorm, actor, play, jdbc)
```

Comment: but now there are two `akka`

Comment: That's because Shadowlands added two to the original list to make it clear how his solution handles multiple "akka" in the list. If there's just one in the original list, it will work as you want.

Answer (score 2):

Here is shortest (though not very efficient on larger lists) solution:

```
 var list=List("scala","finagle","anorm","akka","actor","play","jdbc")
 println(list.sortBy(_ != "akka"))  // List(akka, scala, finagle, anorm, actor, play, jdbc)
```